# merging two dataframes and using the index from one of the dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2, I want to merge the two dataframes

```
df_1
index  variable_df1
1           32
2           31
3           83
4           28


df_2
index     variable_1_df2   variable_2_df2
83281        0.99               0.01
12285        0.77               0.23
42325        0.12               0.23
22211        0.95               0.91


desired merge:
df_merge

index     variable_1_df2   variable_2_df2    variable_df1
83281        0.99               0.01              32
12285        0.77               0.23              31
42325        0.12               0.23              83
22211        0.95               0.91              28
```

I tried to put the index from df2 in a list and put as a column in df1 but ran into errors

also `concat([df1, df2])` get me a lot of nulls

Comment: The index for both the dataframes are not the same. So your concat will have a problem. Is `index` a column name or the actual index of the dataframe?

Comment: What is common between the two so it can be merged

Comment: it's the actual index

Comment: use the example from the link i gave you. It may be the thing you were looking for

Comment: `df2['variable_df1] = df1['variable_df1'].values`.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).